# Bash traps not executing on last cmd for scripts passed in with -c

Tags: bash

Here's an example:

```
$ (newline=$'\n'; bash -c "trap 'trap ERR; echo handler' ERR; set -e;${newline}/bin/false")
```

The handler will execute if I do any of the following:

- remove the newline
- trap on EXIT instead
- add another command at the end

I suspect bash has an optimization to just call exec if there's only one command, and the newline followed by a single command is triggering it.

I have circumstantial evidence: I ran under strace; earlier cmds will vfork then execve, but the last one just calls execv.

I ran into this with GNU make using .ONESHELL and a trap to print the exit code and log filename, but if the last thing fails the trap does not execute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example triggers the handler in GNU Bash 4.4.12(1)-release, Debian GNU/Linux 9.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about this question; I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot about this question.  I contributed a fix to bash [back in 2016](http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.4/ChangeLog):

```
                   4/22
                   ----
builtins/evalstring.c
    - should_suppress_fork: don't suppress the fork if there are any traps
      set, since that requires that we hang around to react to a signal or
      collect the command's exit status and run something.  Fixes bug
      reported by Brian Vandenberg
```

As I had speculated in my question bash indeed has optimizations in place.  It's been awhile since I looked at the code, but it more or less does the following:

1. Parse until a complete expression is identified, evaluate it then interpret or execute what's left after evaluation
2. Repeat (1) until only one expression is left
3. If the last expression requires no assistance from the shell and can be passed to an `exec()` family function, then do that

My fix was to add to the definition of "requires no assistance from the shell" by making it check if any traps are in effect.